# Different AIC values using lm, dlm and dlmodeler

Tags: r, aic, dlm

I would like to compare a model with time varying slope coefficient to a model with constant slope coefficient. In order to do this, I use the R package "dlm" to set up the models and calculate the coefficients, which actually works fine. However, I decided to compare the AIC of the constant coefficient model (using the "dlm" package) to the AIC I get when setting up the equivalent model (which gets me the same estimate for the coefficient as "dlm") with "lm". But they differ heavily. I would have expected the two values for the AIC to agree. Am I missing some statistical point concerning the AIC? Or am I just calculating the AIC in a wrong way (i.e. 2 * dlmMLE(...)$value + 2*p, where p is the number of parameter estimated, since dlmMLE minimises the negative of the loglikelihood using the function optim) when using the "dlm" package? I know that some packages treat the constant term differently, but I couldn't figure out if this is the case here too.
I'll poste some code to make it reproducible what I mean:

> ```
> ## Model
> # y_t      = mu + lambda * x_t + epsilon_t        epislon_t ~ N(0,(sigma_epsilon)^2)
> #Example vectors 1
> set.seed(10)
> y<-rnorm(200)
> y<-scale(y)
> x<-y[1:100]+rnorm(100,sd=2)
> x<-c(x,-y[101:200]-rnorm(100,sd=2))
> x<-scale(x)
> #build the model
> buildModReg2 <- function(u){
>  dV <- exp(u[1])
>  dW <- c(0,0)
>  m0 <- u[2:3]
>  dlmModReg(x, dV = dV, dW = dW, m0 = m0)
> }
> varGuess2 <- var(diff(y))
> muGuess2 <- 0
> lambdaGuess2 <- mean(diff(y))
> parm2 <- c(log(varGuess2), muGuess2, lambdaGuess2)
> mle2 <- dlmMLE(y, parm = parm2, build = buildModReg2)
> #compute the AIC
> aic2 <- 2 * mle2$value + 2 * 2
> aic2 #returns 245.7
> #compare to lm
> lm2 <- lm(y ~ 0 + x)
> AIC(lm2) #570.4
> ```

Comment: If the models are the same but likelihoods differ, then probably the constants in the likelihood due to the different software functions are messed up (as you mention). Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: The safest thing is never to compare results between software only within as some aspects of AIC are arbitrary as @RichardHardy hints.